# React asynchronously rendering multiple components with states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, gpu, gpu.js

I'm trying to make use of GPU.js in a sample CRA React project. I'm trying to make a visible comparison between CPU & GPU calculations, but React "waits" for CPU calculations to finish before showing all results, despite them being in separate components, using separate states.

**Example: In the same component**

```
function Combined() {
  const [gpu, setGpu] = useState('null')
  const [cpu, setCpu] = useState('null')

  useEffect(() => {
    const size = 500
    const matrices = generateMatrices(size)
    setGpu(gpuMultiplyMatrix(matrices, size))
    setCpu(cpuMultiplyMatrix(matrices, size))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      ...
      <div>{gpu && gpu}</div>
      <div>{cpu && cpu}</div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

In the same component, React will wait for `cpuMultiplyMatrix` to finish before rendering the component. I expected this.

[View GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9wKj.jpg)

**Example: Separated components**

GPU

```
function GPUOnly() {
  const [gpu, setGpu] = useState('null')

  useEffect(() => {
    const size = 500
    const matrices = generateMatrices(size)
    gpuMultiplyMatrixAsync(matrices, size).then(result => setGpu(result))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      GPU in separated Component
      <div>{gpu && gpu}</div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  )
}
```

CPU

```
function CPUOnly() {
  const [cpu, setCpu] = useState('null')

  useEffect(() => {
    const size = 500
    const matrices = generateMatrices(size)
    cpuMultiplyMatrixAsync(matrices, size).then(result => setCpu(result))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      CPU in separated Component
      <div>{cpu && cpu}</div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  )
}
```

App

```
import GPUOnly from './components/GPU'
import CPUOnly from './components/CPU'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <GPUOnly />
      <CPUOnly />
    </>
  )
}
```

Despite being separated, React still waits for the CPU calc to finish before it can render the GPU, even though the GPU component finished tasks must faster.

[View GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWWSG.jpg)

I've tried asynchronous calls, & separating them into their own hooks. No changes as useEffect performs the functions within it's callback synchronously.

How can I achieve asynchronous behaviour when rendering multiple components?

Comment: What do the matrix functions do? Javascript engines are single threaded, just throwing async on a function won't make it do its work in parallel with other code.

Comment: The matrices generation generates 2D arrays with random numbers as elements, using Math.random(). The cpu/gpu multiplication functions perform a multiplication on each element in the matrices. Regardless, I completely forgot about JS engines being single threaded.

Comment: You can make your async function yield (and let e.g. React render) by adding something like `const delay = (ms=0) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));` and `await delay();` to suitable places in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*IF* the async calls are run on a background thread (e.g. a web worker), *then* it should work as intended, i.e. the components should finish and render independently. Just because the API is async doesn't necessarily guarantee they run in the background.

A toy example shows the behaviour you are looking for does work on React, in the way you describe: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-pond-s2u1z?file=/src/App.js